# How do I call one function in another function?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, inorder, preorder, postorder

I created functions that are able to get the successor Node in a binary search tree traversing it in all 3 ways, in order, post order, and pre order. My challenge now is try to put them all in a getNextItem method, and call each of those aforementioned functions using the getNextItem method. I know what the skeleton of the getNextItem method should be I just don't know how to complete it. I also included the insert and main method if anyone wanted to test my functions. Please note I cannot change the parameters in the getNextItem method.

```
public class BinaryTree {
    public static final int INORDER = 1;
    public static final int PREORDER = 2;
    public static final int POSTORDER = 3;
    TreeNode root;
    TreeNode currentNode;

    class TreeNode {
        int data;
        TreeNode left, right, parent, root;

        TreeNode(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            left = right = parent = root = null;
        }
    }

    TreeNode insert(TreeNode node, int data) {
        if (node == null) {
            return (new TreeNode(data));
        }
        else {
            TreeNode temp = null;

            if (data <= node.data) {
                temp = insert(node.left, data);
                node.left = temp;
                temp.parent = node;
            }
            else {
                temp = insert(node.right, data);
                node.right = temp;
                temp.parent = node;
            }

            return node;
        }
    }

    public Comparable getNextItem(int orderType) {
        switch (orderType) {
            case INORDER:
                break;
            case PREORDER:
                break;
            case POSTORDER:
                break;
        return;
    }

    TreeNode inOrderSuccessor(TreeNode n) {
        if (n.right != null) {
            return minValue(n.right);
        }

        TreeNode p = n.parent;
        while (p != null && n == p.right) {
            n = p;
            p = p.parent;
        }
        return p;
    }

    TreeNode minValue(TreeNode node) {
        TreeNode current = node;
        while (current.left != null) {
            current = current.left;
        }
        return current;
    }

    TreeNode preorderSuccessor(TreeNode n) {
        if (n.left != null)
            return n.left;

        if (n.right != null)
            return n.right;

        TreeNode curr = n, parent = curr.parent;
        while (parent != null && parent.right == curr) {
            curr = curr.parent;
            parent = parent.parent;
        }

        if (parent == null)
            return null;

        return parent.right;
    }

    TreeNode postorderSuccessor(TreeNode n) {
        if (n == null)
            return null;

        TreeNode parent = n.parent;
        if (parent.right == null || parent.right == n)
            return parent;

        TreeNode curr = parent.right;
        while (curr.left != null)
            curr = curr.left;

        return curr;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
        TreeNode root = null, temp = null, suc = null, suc2 = null, suc3 = null, min = null;
        root = tree.insert(root, 20);
        root = tree.insert(root, 8);
        root = tree.insert(root, 22);
        root = tree.insert(root, 4);
        root = tree.insert(root, 12);
        root = tree.insert(root, 10);
        root = tree.insert(root, 14);
        temp = root.left.right.right;
        suc = tree.inOrderSuccessor(temp);
        System.out.println(
                "Inorder successor of "
                        + temp.data + " is " + suc.data);
        suc = tree.preorderSuccessor(temp);
        System.out.println(
                "Preorder successor of "
                        + temp.data + " is " + suc.data);
        suc = tree.postorderSuccessor(temp);
        System.out.println(
                "Postorder successor of "
                        + temp.data + " is " + suc.data);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest starting with `currentNode = null`, so that the very first call of `getNextItem` will actually return the data of the very *first* node in the given traversal order.

I would also have the class manage its `root` member itself, so that the main program does not have to update it after calling `insert`.

The name `minValue` is not really representative of what it does, as it does not return a node's value, but a node. It could be a method on the `TreeNode` class.

Here is how it could look:

```
class BinaryTree {
    public static final int INORDER = 1;
    public static final int PREORDER = 2;
    public static final int POSTORDER = 3;
    TreeNode root, currentNode;

    public class TreeNode {
        int data;
        TreeNode left, right, parent;

        public TreeNode(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            left = right = parent = null; // There should be no root here.
        }
            
        TreeNode minNode() {
            return left == null ? this : left.minNode();
        }
    }

    public BinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }
 
    public void insert(int newData) {
        root = root == null ? new TreeNode(newData) : insert(root, newData);
    }
    
    private TreeNode insert(TreeNode node, int newData) {
        if (node == null) return new TreeNode(newData);
        if (newData < node.data) {
            node.left = insert(node.left, newData);
            node.left.parent = node;
        } else if (newData > node.data) { 
            node.right = insert(node.right, newData);
            node.right.parent = node;
        }
        return node;
    }

    private TreeNode inOrderSuccessor(TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null) return root.minNode();
        if (node.right != null) return node.right.minNode();
        while (node.parent != null) {
            if (node == node.parent.left) return node.parent;
            node = node.parent;
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    private TreeNode preOrderSuccessor(TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null) return root;
        if (node.left != null) return node.left;
        if (node.right != null) return node.right;
        while (node.parent != null) {
            if (node == node.parent.left && node.parent.right != null) {
                return node.parent.right;
            }
            node = node.parent;
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    private TreeNode postOrderSuccessor(TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null) return root.minNode();
        if (node.parent == null) return null;
        if (node.parent.right == node || node.parent.right == null) return node.parent;
        node = node.parent.right;
        while (node.left == null && node.right != null) {
            node = node.right;
        }
        return node.minNode();
    }
    

    public Comparable getNextItem(int orderType) {
        if (root == null) return null;
        switch (orderType) {
            case INORDER:
                currentNode = inOrderSuccessor(currentNode);
                break;
            case PREORDER:
                currentNode = preOrderSuccessor(currentNode);
                break;
            case POSTORDER:
                currentNode = postOrderSuccessor(currentNode);
                break;
        }
        return currentNode == null ? null : currentNode.data;
    }
    
    public void reset() {
        currentNode = null;
    }

    void print() {
        print(root, "");
    }

    void print(TreeNode node, String tab) {
        if (node == null) return;
        print(node.right, tab + "  ");
        System.out.println(tab + node.data);
        print(node.left, tab + "  ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main tree = new BinaryTree();
        tree.insert(8);
        tree.insert(3);
        tree.insert(10);
        tree.insert(9);
        tree.insert(1);
        tree.insert(6);
        tree.insert(7);
        tree.print();
        tree.reset();
        System.out.println("In-order traversal:");
        while (true) {
            Comparable data = tree.getNextItem(INORDER);
            if (data == null) break;
            System.out.print(data + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        tree.reset();
        System.out.println("Pre-order traversal:");
        while (true) {
            Comparable data = tree.getNextItem(PREORDER);
            if (data == null) break;
            System.out.print(data + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        tree.reset();
        System.out.println("Post-order traversal:");
        while (true) {
            Comparable  data = tree.getNextItem(POSTORDER);
            if (data == null) break;
            System.out.print(data + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer worked. However, I tried fitting it with my insert method, and it didn't work the one you have is public void insert(int newData) but mines is public void insert(Comparable item). So when I tried running it, it gave me an error.

Comment: That's not what you have in the question, though. Your question has `TreeNode insert(TreeNode node, int data)`. If you want a `Comparable` instead of `int`, then you must make that change all the way down to your `TreeNode` class with its `data` member.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think your `*successor` methods need to be recursive; otherwise you won't get the correct successor according to the ordering method. Assuming that you have done that:

The `getNextItem` implies that you keep a cursor (e.g. a current node to traverse on), or you provide a `currentNode` as a parameter. If you don't want an iterative behavior (e.g. if you don't want a cursor), then the second option would be better for you; which is to provide a `currentNode` as a parameter, and then select the appropriate method WRT the order type).

```java
   //..previous code
   public Comparable getNextItem(int orderType, TreeNode currentNode) {
        TreeNode successor = null;
        switch (orderType) {
            case INORDER:
                successor = inOrderSuccessor(currentNode);
                break;
            case PREORDER:
                successor = preOrderSuccessor(currentNode);
                break;
            case POSTORDER:
                successor = postOrderSuccessor(currentNode);
                break;
         } //end of switch
         
         return successor.data;
    }
   //..the rest
```

Please be aware of null checks and so on.

EDIT: If you aren't allowed to change the parameters of the `getNextItem` method, then your tree needs to behave as an iterator, hence you need a cursor. Since you already have a field called `currentNode`, then you can use that as a cursor, initially setting it to `root`.

Then it should look like this:

```java
   //..previous code
   public Comparable getNextItem(int orderType) {
        TreeNode successor = null;
        switch (orderType) {
            case INORDER:
                successor = inOrderSuccessor(this.currentNode);
                break;
            case PREORDER:
                successor = preOrderSuccessor(this.currentNode);
                break;
            case POSTORDER:
                successor = postOrderSuccessor(this.currentNode);
                break;
         } //end of switch
         //keep the cursor up to date.
         this.currentNode = successor;
         return successor.data;
    }
   //..the rest
```

For this option to work properly, you also need to have a `reset` method which sets the `currentNode` to `root`, as well as keeping an eye on `null` values.

I would suggest a few refactors as well, like to encapsulate node management in the binary tree and make sure that your order algorithms work correctly.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the parameter of the getNextItem method

Comment: @MarcusAvailo, such "rules" should be listed in your question.

Comment: I tried to expand the answer a bit more to cover that need, but indeed you need to list those rules in your question.